# skip a line from a txt file

Tags: python, selenium, line, txt

Hello I want to send a random key from my txt file, and skip if there is an empty line
my problem is that my code is only sending one letter and not the entire line

here is my code

```
with open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        file = f.readline()
    for word in file:
        if not word.strip():
            continue
        elif not 0 < len(word) < 280:
            continue

sleep(1)
        
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[role="textbox"][data-testid="tweetTextarea_0"]').send_keys(random.choice(word))

        sleep(1)
```

Comment: This is pure python question, it is not related with selenium.

Comment: Import `random` and then do `random.choice(open('file.txt').readlines()).strip("\n")`

Comment: Your `for` loop is iterating over the contents of a single line. I believe you want to loop through the lines themselves, in which case, you should use a `while` loop and read until `readline` fails.